# Itunes connect has changed to invalid binary

Tags: binary, app-store-connect

After i upload my application to app store after is done is show me in iphone application "has changed to invalid binary" and in the itunesconnect is show 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vPJN.png

any solution ?

Comment: I've just hit this issue.. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1):

My experience:

[image]

There are many potential bug in your project.

1 .there may be private function(the third part SDK ,e.g. Reveal) in the project

2 .Missing Info.plist key - the app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.

Solve:

1. Generally，you will receive email from apple. I suggest you read it seriously. 
   It will tell you what should you do because they find out "invalid binary"...
2. Then solve the problem.